# Is there any pattern to the continued fraction of $\sqrt[3]{2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Is there any pattern to the continued fraction of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ ?  Wolfram Alpha returns for [cube root of 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+cube+root+of+2):

> $\sqrt[3]{2}=$ [1; 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 8, 1, 14, 1, 10, 2, 1, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 14,
>   3, 12, 1, 15, 3, 1, 4, 534, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 121, 1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 3, 2, 2, 41, 1, 1, ...]

So the answer is likely no.  There certainly won't be any repeating pattern such as:

$$ 1+\sqrt{2} = 2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \dots }}}$$

But I was hoping maybe for a pattern like we might find for the number $e = 2.718\dots$:

$$ e = [2; 1, \color{blue}{2}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{4}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{6}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{8}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{10}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{12}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{14}, 1, 1, \color{blue}{16}, 1, 1, 1, ...]$$

So in fact $e = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \dots$ has a nicer continued fraction pattern than $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

You can actually derive the continued fraction of $e$ ([Henry Cohn](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601660)) - but I haven't worked through it yet.

---

### Proposal: Tree-Like Continued Fraction

If we try to derive a continued fraction for cube roots let's see how we get in trouble:

$$ \sqrt[3]{2} \approx 1 $$

That's really lousy guess but let's see how far we are off:

$$ \sqrt[3]{2} - 1 = \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}} \tag{$\square$}$$

so let's backtrack we actually needed two pieces of information:

$$ 
\sqrt[3]{2} \approx 1 
\hspace{0.25in}
\textbf{and}
\hspace{0.25in} 
\sqrt[3]{4} \approx 1 $$

The cube root of 4 is still not quite $2 = \sqrt[3]{8}$.  Now let's try:

$$ \sqrt[3]{4} - 1 = \frac{3}{1 + \sqrt[3]{4} + \sqrt[3]{16}}
=  \frac{3}{1 + \sqrt[3]{4} + 2\sqrt[3]{2}}
\tag{$\Delta$}
$$

And then run all of this back into the equation we started from:

$$ \sqrt[3]{2} - 1 = \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}}
= \cfrac{1}{1 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}} \right) + \left( 1 + \frac{3}{1 + \sqrt[3]{4} + 2\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)}$$

Let's make it look a little bit cleaner but the same:

$$ \sqrt[3]{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}}
= 1 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}}  +  \frac{3}{1  + 2\sqrt[3]{2}+ \sqrt[3]{4}}}$$

Using the $\square$ and $\Delta$ pattern we can get a regular infinite pattern this way.

---

## Clarification

I am being repeatedly asked to clarify the question what do I mean by "pattern" the truth is **I don't know**.  To this end I make two points:

- the are transcedental numbers with clear patterns if their continued fraction such as $e$.  We find that every third digit is an even number starting with $2$ and increasing by $+2$.  Every other digit is $1$.
- I have already proposed a "tree-like" generalized continued fraction that may have recursive properties similar to what repeated patterns havefor numberes like $\sqrt{n}$
- This paper by [Yann Bugeaud](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/research/groups/CDMTCS/researchreports/398yann.pdf) states continued fraction digits definitely cannot have any pattern:

> Let $\alpha = [0; a_1, a_2,...]$ be an algebraic
>   number of degree at least three. One of our criteria implies that the
>   sequence of partial quotients $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ of $\alpha$ cannot be generated by a finite automaton, and that the complexity function of $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ cannot increase too slowly.

Personally it's hard for me to fathom a number that doesn't satisfy any pattern.  There must be some pattern.  My question is then what could we try instead?

Lastly, if the cubic case is this intractable, I might shift my attention to the quadratic case where more results are known...

Comment: "Pattern" seems like a vague concept to me.

Comment: It is a folklore conjecture that all algebraic numbers of degree $d > 2$ are unexceptional, i.e. they look like a typical real number from Khintchine's theorem.

Comment: @ToddTrimble the question is deliberately vague.   the continued fraction digits of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ can't repeat.  so we need to find some other notion of pattern.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002945

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "we can get a regular infinite pattern this way?"

Comment: It still might be unclear what you're asking. The vagueness of "pattern" means that an answer of 'no', which you consider likely, is essentially impossible to prove. Would the recursive formula due to Bombieri and van der Poorten (referenced in the oeis link) qualify as an answer of 'yes'?

Comment: @ToddTrimble they say "However, such a formula does not necessarily usefully increase our understanding of the nature of the partial quotients of such a number."

Comment: So then, I guess you are saying that doesn't qualify as a 'yes' in your view. Which leaves one still to wonder what might plausibly qualify... (I don't mean to be argumentative; I'm honestly unsure what the parameters of the problem are).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a well-known open problem.

Comment: The fact that it's the continued fraction expansion of the cube root of $2$ can be reasonably considered a pattern. Obviously, this sort of "pattern" is outside the bounds of what was intended.  But then it's important to say something about what bounds are intended.

Comment: John, your motivation is clearly noble as you've hit on a pretty well-known open problem. However, as for your statement "Personally it's hard for me to fathom a number that doesn't satisfy any pattern", the way to see this statement doesn't make much sense is: consider the decimal expansion of $\pi$. If that can fail to "satisfy a pattern" (which is a much more famous and intensely studied conjecture) then why not the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt[3]{2}$? And if you think that too can satisfy a pattern, I'd say your definition of "pattern" is too broad to be of much use.

Comment: For the representation of a continued fraction there is the method using products of 2x2-matrices - a set of matrices $M_k$ having the k'th cf-coefficients in its edge; for periodic continued fractions this runs into an eigenvalue problem of the partial product of $P_n =M_1 \times ... \times M_n$ where the matrices contain the periodic tail of the coefficients of the cf. For cubic roots the same can be expressed with 3x3 matrices of the obvious form; and because 3x3-matrices of integer entries can have cubic roots in their eigenvalues, that generalization provides then a periodic pattern.

Comment: If we allow the more general framework of generalized continued fractions, then there are indeed representations of $x^{m/n}$ which can be expressed by simple formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Roots_of_positive_numbers

Answer (score 15):

To my knowledge, much more general question is open:

[OPEN DIOPHANTINE PROBLEMS p. 15](http://www.ams.org/distribution/mmj/vol4-1-2004/waldschmidt.pdf)

> Essentially nothing is known about the continued fraction expansion of a real algebraic number of degree ≥ 3; one does not know the answer to any of the following two questions.
>
> **Question 2.9**. Does there exist a real algebraic number of degree ≥ 3 with bounded partial quotients?
>
> **Question 2.10** . Does there exist a real algebraic number of degree ≥ 3 with unbounded partial quotients?

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+for+sqrt%28i%29) there might be chance for the Hurwitz expansion of
$\sqrt{i}$ which starts

```
 [1 + i; -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + 2i, 2 + 2i, -2 + , ...]
```

Comment: You get algebraic numbers of degree $2$ from periodic **simple** continued fractions, where the elements are positive integers.  Here they are not integers, so it's not surprising that the result is not of degree $2$.

Comment: Yeah, I would think here, the point is that it's degree two over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so you should get periodic partial quotients when your coefficients can be in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: You are right.  $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has a nice continued fraction when the coefficients can be in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ ...

Answer (score 10):

(I have a comment regarding your Tree-Like Continued Fraction generalization, except I only have enough reputation to write answers.)

Given algebraic $x_0$, an instance of your generalization can be found by searching for some function who has a fixed point at $x_0$ and is the inverse of a polynomial.

Suppose a polynomial $p(x)$ has a root at $x_0$. Following your example, if $x_0 = \sqrt[3]{2}-1$, then we can pick the minimal polynomial $p(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x -1$. Set $p(x) = 0$ to write $\frac{1}{x} = x^2 + 3x + 3$. Thus, $x_0$ is a fixed point of $f(x)$:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+3x+3}
$$

The Tree-like continued fraction can then be directly read off of $f(x)$. Going back to the general case: if $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$, then 
$$
f(x) = \frac{-a_0}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^{i-1}}
$$

We make no restriction on whether $|f'(x_0)|<1$.

You have thought of this implicitly already, but I feel that this is a more explicit way of writing down what are you looking for.

Answer (score 6):

This is the Hermite Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_problem

The Jacobi-Perron algorithm attempts to solve this.

Mittal and Gupta have defined Bifurcating Continued Fractions- http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002227 http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008060

Specifically, they say the pair $2^{1/3}$ and $2^{2/3}$ has the expansion:
$1,\overline{1,2} $ and $ \overline{1,0}$

Lehmer talks of Ternary Continued Fractions - https://oeis.org/A000962/a000962.pdf

How it all fits together I have no idea.

Comment: It seems that Mittal and Gupta rediscovered the Jacobi-Perron continued fractions and algorithm (which Jacobi started to devise in direct response to Hermite):

1) http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/scuola_orientamento/alumni/laureati/lamonica/Summary.pdf

2) https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540054979