# A question in regards to finding the roots of numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, na.numerical-analysis, rootfinding

A simple algorithm for finding the square root of any integer goes as the following:

example $√25$**:** $25 - 1 -3 - 5 - 7 - 9 = 0$

We have deducted 5 numbers (-1, -3, -5, -7, -9) without resulting in a negative number, and thus the answer is 5

example $√27$**:** $27 - 1 -3 - 5 - 7 - 9 = 2$

We have deducted 5 numbers (-1, -3, -5, -7, -9) without resulting in a negative number, and thus the answer is 5.?, but in this case we have a remainder of 2 and thus we have to complete a decimal for 5.?

We have two ways to deal with the remainder:

**First way**: We can multiply $27 * 100$, or $27 * 10000$ or $27 * 1000000$ (every additional 00 will result in a more precise answer:

$2700 - 1 -3 -5 -7 -9 -11 -13 -15 -17 -19 -21 -23 -25 -27 -29 -31 -33 -35 -37 -39 - 41 -43 -45 -47 -49 -51 -53 -55 -57 -59 -61 -63 -65 -67 -69 -71 -73 -75 -77 -79 -81 -83 -85 - 87 -89 -91 -93 -95 -97 -99 -101 = 99$

We have deducted 51 numbers and there for we know the first decimal for √27 = 5.1?

the more 00's we put at the end of 27, the more decimals we will get.

**Second way:** $27−1−3−5−7−9=2$  We take the remainder of 2 and divide it by what would of been the next number to deduct in the sequences. In this case it would of been 11

$2/11 = 0.18181818181818....$

Here is the funny thing: We then take the result and we can add it to what would of been the next number to deduct in the sequence minus 1. In this case 11-1 = 10  and 10 + 0.18181818181818 = 10.181818181818

$2/10.181818181818181818 = 0.19642857142857142$

and we repeat the process until there is no more change:

$2/10.19642857142857142 = 0.19614711033274956$

$2/10.19614711033274956 = 0.19615252490553076$

$2/10.19615252490553076 = 0.1961524207405411$

$2/10.1961524207405411 = 0.19615242274445532$

$2/10.19615242274445532 = 0.19615242270590422$

At the end when there is no more change (and without rounding the results to begin with)

$√27 = 5.196152422706631880582....$

I know that the first way can work for other roots, for example: for finding the cube root of 150: $150 - 1-7 - 19 - 37 -61 = 25$ (For cubes the sequence is growing by $6*1$, $6*2$, $6*3$ ...) we have deducted 5 numbers without resulting in a negative number, and thus the answer is 5.?. The more 000 (for cubes it’s 000 zeros) we put at the end of 150, the more precise will be our result.

However, my question is if there is a similar sieve as the **second way** for cube roots, fourth roots, etc. ?

Comment: It's much easier to just punch a few buttons on a calculator, isn't it?

Comment: Lol!!! yes indeed But the theory behind it is interesting to me. It's the need to know, even (even if not practical).

Comment: It seems like what you’re doing might be equivalent to using continued fractions. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265690/continued-fraction-of-a-square-root . It might be a longshot, but you could look at the "Proposal" in this question and see if it gives you any ideas: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224340/is-there-any-pattern-to-the-continued-fraction-of-sqrt32

Comment: The sequence for cube is $a_n=(2n-1)^2-n(n+1)=3n^2+3n+1$. So, for $x=(n+r)^3$, after deleting $n$ terms (hence, $n^3$) and dividing by the $n$th term we get, $r+\frac{(r^3-r+3n(r^2-r))}{3n^2+3n+1}$. Here latter term is again very small as $r<1$. That approximately gives $r$.